# Why isn't my serialScroll working?

Tags: jquery, css

If you take a look at [issue now solved] you'll notice a sliding layout with 50% opacity buttons on either side of the proposed viewport. I'm using serialScroll, and I want the buttons to take me to the slide adjacent to the currently viewed one. For some reason, it's currently taking me to the end of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Serial Scroll but try setting your selector to the  like this:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
        $('#screen').serialScroll({
        target:'#sections ul',
```

If you arent sold on serial scroll, check out jQuery Cycle, it does this as well and is super awesome :)